# Thread / Process Blocking not working as expected

Tags: c#, multithreading

The following is a highly simplified demonstration of my code structure:

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static ConcurrentQueue<string> lst = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
        static bool bExit = false;

        static void Main(string[] args)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            lst.Enqueue("LINE " + i.ToString());
        }

        Thread threadCurrent = Thread.CurrentThread;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // #1 this block causes the process to exit at about line 556 on my PC

            //while (threadCurrent.IsAlive)
            //{
            //  Thread.Sleep(500);
            //}

            /////

            // #2 this block works as expected and exits after line 999 is printed

            //while (threadCurrent.IsAlive || lst.Count > 0)
            //{
            //  Thread.Sleep(500);
            //}

            /////

            // #3 this block never exits the process

            threadCurrent.Join();

            // forced queue flush would go here

            /////

            bExit = true;
        });

        Thread threadWorker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker));

        threadWorker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        threadWorker.Start();
    }

    static private void Worker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string s;

            if (lst.TryDequeue(out s))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            if (bExit)
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

See the 3 blocks in the Task.Run() section. Run this in the debugger. With method #1, on my PC, the process exits about half way through. #2 works as expected and #3 hangs forever.

The idea is that the main thread will post messages to a queue and return immediately while a worker thread processes it. I want to ensure all messages in the queue are processed before the process exits even if the main thread has exited. Method #2 accomplishes this, but I just don't like the sleep, but I'll live with it if that's what I have to... :).

Method #1 proves that the main thread is in fact exiting, no? So I would think that Method #3 would accomplish the same thing WITHOUT the Sleep? But the .Join never returns, why?

Comment: Any specific reason you're working with threads instead of `Task`s?

Comment: @JohnWu The main thread is a thread, not a task. If I make Worker a task, it doesn't block the process from exiting. Has to be a thread for that.

Comment: If the main thread exits then your process is destroyed. That's a Windows thing, not .net. Therefore, if you have threads that are not marked as background (in your case, `threadWorker`), the main thread will wait for them before exiting. As to know why `IsAlive` is returning false, I don't know. I suppose that's because the main thread isn't executing any managed code anymore, but the inconsistency between `IsAlive` and `Join` is a surprising design choice. Probably an unforeseen side-effect.

Comment: Also, to solve your problem without sleep, you should replace `bExit` by a `ManualResetEvent` and wait on it.

Comment: @KevinGosse I'm not sure what you mean by ManualResetEvent? I put the sleep in there so it's not in a tight loop pegging the CPU. What's interesting is that when I looked at this code a few years ago, .Join worked only if the debugger was attached, but not outside of it. Now it doesn't even work with the debugger, so I guess they fixed that part lol...

Comment: @SledgeHammer Instead of looping on a condition, just wait on a ManualResetEvent, and have the other thread signal it when the work is done

Comment: @KevinGosse Are you SURE, the main thread waits for other foreground threads? My understanding is that the main thread exits, but the process is kept alive until all foreground threads exit. But I guess your explanation might explain why .Join isn't working.

Comment: @KevinGosse Ah... gotcha… yeah, I don't want to do it like that. That would require all users of my class to actually read the docs :). This way I handle that behind the scenes for them. Guess I'll have to live with the Sleep method then.

Comment: @KevinGosse I don't think your explanation is correct. If you put a breakpoint on the while loop with IsAlive, after an interation or two, you can clearly see in the thread window that the main thread gets marked as [Thread Destroyed].

Comment: @KevinGosse also if you put a small timeout in the .Join as in .Join(100) you can also see the main thread getting marked as Thread Destroyed.

Comment: @SledgeHammer 100% certain. It happens here for .net core: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a7f6a9d7a1302c355bbf87aba81143e586bdfad8/src/vm/assembly.cpp#L1827  after exiting the entry point (RunMain) the thread will wait for others in RunMainPost

Comment: @KevinGosse Hmm... further experimentation with the .Join timeout, seems to me like IsAlive detects the [Thread Destroyed] state, but .Join doesn't. When I put a longer timeout (like 5 seconds), it still returns false although IsAlive returns false and the main thread has clearly finished.

Comment: @SledgeHammer In fact, we can see what happens in the method that waits for the other threads: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/1a34c72e9e719c9d3879c2a519bf70a05f42869c/src/vm/threads.cpp#L5983  the main thread is first marked as dead `FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pCurThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ReportDead);` and only then it waits for the other threads to exit. That explains the inconsistent behavior of `IsAlive`

Comment: When I get some time I'll try running a custom build of .net core without the `FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pCurThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ReportDead)` part. If my analysis is correct, then `IsAlive` will return true as you would expect. That should make a nice article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprising behavior, but that can be explained.

First, you've got to know that the lifetime of the process is tied to the lifetime of the main thread ([aka primary thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/about-processes-and-threads)). I thought that was a Windows thing, [but according to Raymon Chen this is a C thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100827-00/?p=13023).

In any case, the bottom line is: the .NET runtime has to keep the main thread alive.

So what happens when you exit the `Main` method of your program? By contract, the .NET runtime has to wait for any thread that is not marked as background. It does so in the [`RunMainPost`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/a7f6a9d7a1302c355bbf87aba81143e586bdfad8/src/vm/assembly.cpp#L1827) method, which in turn will call [`WaitForOtherThreads`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/1a34c72e9e719c9d3879c2a519bf70a05f42869c/src/vm/threads.cpp#L5983).
This explains why calling `Thread.Join` on the main thread won't succeed until all the foreground threads have finished their work.

But then, why is `mainThread.IsAlive` returning false?

First, you must know that `IsAlive` isn't directly bound to a thread. Instead, it calls [`ThreadIsRunning`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/b31ec0562a7e916301585001968ac5522aa20e84/src/vm/comsynchronizable.cpp#L101). This will return true if the underlying thread is not dead **and** if it's not flagged with `TS_ReportDead` or `TS_Dead` (that's because the runtime keeps the threads a bit longer after they're reported dead to the managed code, to do some bookkeeping/tidying).

Back to `WaitForOtherThreads`, if you check the code you can see this:

```
if (!OtherThreadsComplete())
{
    TSLockHolder.Release();

    FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pCurThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ReportDead);

    DWORD ret = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
    while (CLREventWaitWithTry(&m_TerminationEvent, INFINITE, TRUE, &ret))
    {
    }
    _ASSERTE(ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0);
}
```

The `m_TerminationEvent` is set by the last thread to die. But the important bit is the `FastInterlockOr((ULONG *) &pCurThread->m_State, Thread::TS_ReportDead);`: **the main thread is marking itself as dead before waiting on the others**. It explains why `IsAlive` is false.

I've confirmed that hypothesis by building a custom version of .NET Core and commenting out the line. After that, `IsAlive` reports true.

Why is it done that way? I can only guess, but I think this is just to make the runtime code simpler. By marking the main thread as dead, other threads that actually die can check (in the aforementioned bookkeeping code) if all other threads are dead, and in that case set the `m_TerminationEvent`. This is slightly more elegant than checking "are all other threads dead except one". Just a guess though.

Comment: Interesting read. Thanks for investigating. "calling Thread.Join on the main thread won't succeed until all the foreground threads have finished their work." is the key take away here. Looks like the IsAlive is a work-around for what I'm trying to accomplish without requiring the user to explicitly shut down my class.

Answer (score 0):

### Why, OP?

In your example, you add to the queue and *then* start a thread to process it. I would like to point out that this serves no purpose; you could just add to the queue and then proceed to process them one by one on the same thread. Or you could do away with the queue entirely and simple process them instead of queuing them, all in series.

### Maybe this?

So, for the purposes of my answer, I'm going to assume that you *don't* want that; perhaps the operation that retrieves the items to be worked on is expensive, and you want to be able to add the queue concurrent with the worker thread so that it doesn't have to wait for the queue to be ready in order to get started. Therefore my example starts the worker thread before adding to the queue, allowing it to start before the queue setup is complete.

### Using the BlockingCollection's features

The conventional way to process a queue of items this way is to use a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx), which handles almost all the details for you.

Your worker method could be as simple as this:

```
static private void Worker(BlockingCollection<string> queue)
{
    while (queue.Count > 0 || !queue.IsAddingCompleted)  //Exit if there are no items and no more are on the way
    {
        var item = queue.Take();        //Wait until the queue has at least one item, then take it
        Foo(item);                      //Whatever processing you need to do
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
    var queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    var task = Task.Run(() => Worker(queue));  //OK to start it first, it'll run in parallel
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var item = "LINE " + i.ToString();
        queue.Add(item);
    }
    queue.CompleteAdding();  //Tell the Worker the queue is complete.
    task.Wait();             //Wait for Worker to finish. 
}
```

This will set up a queue which will

1. Block any effort to `Take()` an item until one is available. So you don't need to signal when a new item is added and don't need to worry about concurrency. Blocking is lightweight; the O/S won't schedule the thread for execution until the queue has been signaled.
2. Allow thread-safe adds
3. Allow the main thread to signal when it is finished adding.
4. Allow the worker thread to keep processing until the main thread is finished adding.
5. Synchronize processing without using `Join()`.
6. Leave the Main thread alive, but unscheduled, until Worker is complete. This avoids worrying about whether exiting the main thread will have a bad effect.
7. Capture any exception when the task is `Wait()`ed (if you use threads, an unhandled exception will blow up the whole thing)

See the [complete working example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b1U69e). I've added delays and logging statements so you can see how the threads interact. The number inside the brackets is the thread ID.

Sample output:

```
2018-07-17 01:45:40.785 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 0'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.785 [2C1] {Worker} Processing item 'LINE 0'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.832 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 1'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.863 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 2'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.894 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 3'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.894 [2C1] {Worker} Processing item 'LINE 1'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.926 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 4'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.957 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 5'
2018-07-17 01:45:40.988 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 6'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.004 [2C1] {Worker} Processing item 'LINE 2'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.019 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 7'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.051 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 8'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.082 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 9'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.113 [2C1] {Worker} Processing item 'LINE 3'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.113 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 10'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.144 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 11'
2018-07-17 01:45:41.176 [150] {Main} Adding item 'LINE 12'
(truncated)
```

See also [producer-consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Obviously this is a stripped down example for the basis of illustrating the problem. 1) Why? the PROCESSING of items is expensive. I don't want to tie up the calling thread since it doesn't need a response. 2a) the order of task vs. starting the worker thread isn't important. 2b) again this was a sample to illustrate the issue. real world posting of messages doesn't happen there. 3) Tasks don't block the process from exiting, foreground threads do. 4) This is a library and developers never read docs.I can't rely on them to wait on their end. I wait for them "magically"

Comment: There was a reason I didn't use BlockingCollection :). I don't remember it right now... seems like it should work for my needs... it's thread safe, cancellable and blocking... but there was some issue I ran into I believe... I might try it again to see if I can remember...

Comment: Regardless of BlockingCollection vs. my blocking queue implementation, you didn't really answer the question since the question was about the .Join not working.

Comment: About that. I took a complete cut and paste and was unable to reproduce. Is this a consistent and repeatable problem? What version of .NET?

Comment: Yup. 100% repeatable. Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5 .Net 4.7.1. I remember at some point, the .Join worked with the debugger attached, but not if you just ran it with Ctrl+F5. I think that was probably either 4.5.x or 4.6.x with 2015.

Comment: so I played around with BlockingCollection today and I remembered why I didn't want to use it :). 1) cancellation is a bit more of a PITA then in my implementation 2) when you cancel, BlockingCollection throws an exception. 3) my implementation is lighter weight just the few features I needed -- speed is important for this... any ms's I can save I will.